# iOS Facebook and Google login at the same time?

Tags: ios, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google+ and facebook sign  ins in the same app. I followed the instructions by Parse and Google and I first successfully implemented Facebook login. Then I started to follow the google instructions. After doing that, now I'm having these 2 functions in my AppDelegate.swift file:

For google:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey],
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

For facebook:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

Do I need to combine these 2 blocks of code into 1 as seen in some posts such as

[Google SignIn SFSafariViewController/WebView redirects to Google.com after accepting permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907831/google-signin-sfsafariviewcontroller-webview-redirects-to-google-com-after-accep)

or they can stay like that in 2 different blocks?
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You need to combine them.  The simplest way is to use an || on the return statement.  Try this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: nil)  ||
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey] as? String)
}
```

Comment: hey thanks this is really cool. I don't know if you have a moment but can you explain how it works? Returning "or" || seems unsafe..how does it decide/know which handler to use?

Comment: thanks -- & no prob!  Both the Facebook and the Google delegate functions are designed to return FALSE if the url was not meant for them, and TRUE if the url is successfully handled.  So it's ok to call them both if necessary and let them tell you the url isn't meant for them.  If either function is successful then we pass on the TRUE value.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url) {
        return true
    } else if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url) {
        return true
    } else if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        ) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be well served to use Google Identity Toolkit (now repackaged as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?utm_campaign=Firebase_announcement_awareness_general_en_05-18-16_&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=site#key_functions)) to achieve this and allow extensions to other IDP's as well