# Facebook and Google sign in with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-signin

I have two custom sign in Buttons for Google and Facebook on the screen. Here is my code written in `AppDelegate` which causes the problem which I will explain after the code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)



        return true
    }
     func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

            return true
    }
```

If I write this code then after clicking the OK button here:

[image]

The screen doesn't close up and stays there. But the Google screen works perfectly if we click the "Allow" button. But If I use this code only:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)



            return true
        }
```

And remove other function then the Facebook "OK" button works fine. Why doesn't Facebook work when I add this function?

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
            openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
                if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }

                return true
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594702/google-sign-in-for-ios-error-cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-string-anyob/35594731#35594731

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 May I update my question because after applying your answer still I am not able to work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for me

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: nil)  ||
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey] as? String)
}
```

[iOS Facebook and Google login at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125280/ios-facebook-and-google-login-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
     return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

// Please test this condition first, if it's works put (or) condition int return statement for GIDSignIn flag values

Answer (score 0):

This below func in Swift 3.0 works for iOS 8.0 and above.

// Fallback on earlier versions

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return (FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application( application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation) || GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation))
}
```